# how to set fixed decimal in editext field after second digit is entered ? similar to the atm machine screen that shows 00.00

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie in java, may I ask how to make the editText show the decimal ? I am making a screen that is similar to the Atm machine which shows decimal as 00.00

This is the code I wrote which only shows the input number:

```
public class ATMain extends Activity {

        // declare a btntype for the button
        View.OnClickListener btnType = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId()) {  //to enable the input show the value in edittext after click it 
                        case R.id.btnOne:
                            value = value + 1;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnTwo:
                            value = value + 2;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnThree:
                            value = value + 3;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnFour:
                            value = value + 4;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnFive:
                            value = value + 5;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnSix:
                            value = value + 6;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnSeven:
                            value = value + 7;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnEight:
                            value = value + 8;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnNine:
                            value = value + 9;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnTen:
                            value = value + 0;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnTTen:
                            value = value + 0 + "" + 0;
                            extNum.setText(value);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnClear:  // to clear the data input
                            extNum.setText("");
                            value = "";
                            break;
                    }
                }
        };
```

Comment: maybe it's me but I have no idea what you're talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you `value` is a `Double`,

Instead of what you used `extNum.setText(value);`

You can use this:

```
extNum.setText( String.format( "%.2f", value) );
```

Comment: Thanks I able to get the decimal

Comment: Glad to hear, happy coding :-)